# Sorting 5 arrays in one function

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

If I have 5 arrays and one array of pointers that contains all of the 5 arrays, and I need to write a function that will sort every single one of the arrays  using the pointers array only, how can I do that?

The function needs to sort every single one of the array starting from the index 1 (!) and not 0.

```
int arr1[] = { 3, 9, 6, 7 };
int arr2[] = { 2, 5, 5 };
int arr3[] = { 0 };
int arr4[] = { 1, 6 };
int arr5[] = { 4, 5, 6, 2, 1 };
int * parr[] = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5 };
```

I know how to sort one array but I got a bit lost when I tried to sort every single one of the arrays using the pointers array in the most efficient way possible. Maybe there's an option to sort every array but in one loop? Because it seems a bit weird to do a whole "for" loop for every single one of the arrays

**NOTE** the first element of each array indicates the size of each one. For example : in `arr1[0]` is 3 so the amount of numbers that will come after the index 0 in that array is 3 (9,6,7).

Comment: `void multi_sort(size_t n, int *parr[n]){ for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) single_sort(parr[i]); }`

Comment: Do you have artificial restrictions to only use the pointer array "in the most efficient way possible" ? I.e. no other creation of variables is allowed? Is calling library functions allowed? Can the pointer to the not-to-be-sorted array 0 be overwritten? What is your level of experience? I.e. is the proposal to use a loop a new idea to you? In short, if there are any non-obvious requirements, please explain them. Can you show your code for sorting one array? I.e. "What have you tried?".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: What is the expected output? After the sort, do you want `arr1` to contain `{3, 6, 7, 9}`?

Answer (score 2):

You can call in a loop standard C function `qsort` for each element of the array `parr`.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    return ( *( const int * )b < *( const int * )a ) -
           ( *( const int * )a < *( const int * )b );
}          

int main(void) 
{
    int arr1[] = { 3, 9, 6, 7 };
    int arr2[] = { 2, 5, 5 };
    int arr3[] = { 0 };
    int arr4[] = { 1, 6 };
    int arr5[] = { 4, 5, 6, 2, 1 };
    int * parr[] = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5 };

    const size_t N = sizeof( parr ) / sizeof( *parr );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        qsort( parr[i] + 1, parr[i][0], sizeof( int ), cmp );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < parr[i][0] + 1; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", parr[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3 6 7 9 
2 5 5 
0 
1 6 
4 1 2 5 6
```

Comment: `The function needs to sort every single one of the array starting from the index 1 (!) and not 0.` - You failed :D

Comment: @kaldoran It seems you are unable to understand the shown demonstrative program.

Comment: I think you win here, I've reread the code and the question, my bad. [Btw, was just supposed to be a joke at first]