# How to know what is the length of pointer in array of pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have 5 arrays and one array of pointers, I need to know what is the length of each array in the array of pointers(not sizeof). 
How i do it?

```
int arr1[] = { 3, 9, 6, 7 };
int arr2[] = { 2, 5, 5 };
int arr3[] = { 0 };
int arr4[] = { 1, 6 };
int arr5[] = { 4, 5, 6, 2, 1 };
int* arr6[] = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5 };
```

Comment: based on all the previous versions of this homework, isn't the answer found in the arrays themselves?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot. Once converted to `int*` their sizes are irrevocably lost to the compiler. On runtime an array of ints has no concept of size. You should either: have their sizes recorded elsewhere, or code it implicitly (say, for example, the last element should always be some specified, otherwise non-used, constant, like `0` or `-1`).

Comment: not quite a duplicate, but this question seems to have a better understanding of this homework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191792/sorting-5-arrays-in-one-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an *array* has been converted into a pointer (like the elements of the array `arr6`), there's no way to find the number of elements in it (in the original array).
A simplified version is:

```
int arr1[] = { 3, 9, 6, 7 };
int *p = arr1;
/* Now, there's no way to know the number of elements in arr1 solely
   from the pointer 'p' */
```

Either you have keep size information yourself. One way is to have another array for sizes:

```
int* arr6[] = { arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5 };
size_t sz_arr6[] = {sizeof arr1/sizeof arr1[0], sizeof arr2/sizeof arr2[0], ...};
```

This you know index, you know `sz_arr6[i]` corresponds to the number of elements in `arr6[i]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17, it's easy: `std::size(arr)`, from `<iterator>`.

Before that, use `std::distance(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr))` (using the same header).

Comment: I think OP wants the length of the arrays after they are in `arr6` (converted to pointers). Like, how many items are in `arr6[0]`?

Comment: yes, i want to know how many items their in arr6[0] or arr6[1]

Comment: @user7415633: Why would you not mention such a fundamental thing? :-S

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a pointer to the first item of the array. From this, there is no way to tell how long the array is in general.

You will have to keep track of the lengths as well.